# lstm for prediction of future time series values with Keras

Tags: time-series, keras, prediction, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to make prediction of future values for a multivariate time series. I use this code as the template, but modified the output activation to linear

```
https://gist.github.com/karpathy/587454dc0146a6ae21fc
```

The input data is a sequence of 8 dimensional vector of double values. The output is the same 8 dimensional vector one time period ahead of the input sequence. This is the reason for choosing the linear activation.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, input_dim=len(chars),return_sequences=True)) #minesh witout specifying the input_length
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True)) #- original
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(chars))))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

I am new to Keras and RNN. Could someone confirm this design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 8x2 inputs in each sample, for every of those 8 time step you encode 512 features that you keep track of. Then again, 512 values... The number of parameters must be huge? I hope that you have enough data and variety in the patterns to make use of that huge number of parameters, otherwise you will overfit.

I would also avise you to use dropout for the LSTM like this :

```
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, dropout_W = 0.2)) #- original
```

There is also the feature dropout_U, but I would not use that one. The LSTM has multiple gates as you should know, each of these gates are dense layers, so you can choose on which one you want to apply the dropout. Best practice is to apply it on the inputs gate (dropout_W) and not on recurrent gate (dropout_U).

Otherwise the overall architecture makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.